# cant see or able to open a pdf and image in github

Tags: github

When i find some resources in github repo.. i can read the .md file  but the attched pdf or image file i cant access/ open/ download/ view.. is it a browser issue (tried in Chrome and brave) or something else..

https://github.com/tssovi/grokking-the-object-oriented-design-interview/blob/master/media-files/amazon.jpg

i am trying to view the png file..

[this is what i can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBfEQ.png)

tried downloading it. this and that.. nothing works

Comment: Maybe you have a slow internet connection? First check the Console tab of Chrome Dev Tools on the github link you posted to check for errors. Secondly, open the Networks tab and refresh the page, then check if the image in question was correctly fetched. The status code of the `amazon.jpg` request should be 200.